# How many times do we need to sample to get the sampling distribution of means?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, central-limit-theorem

I was looking into the central limit theorem and noticed that every article talks about how big the sample size should be but they never indicate how many times should we be sampling to get the sampling distribution of means.

Is there any minimum number of times we should be sampling the population?
What is the significance of this number?

Answer (score 0):

If your estimator is unbiased and consistent, one sample that is large enough is already sufficient. The expected value of your estimator function converges to the population as the number of observations in a single sample is increased and the standard error that you calculate will provide you with the SD of the sampling distribution. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.